# Using a hashmap with int as key and need to change it to use long

Tags: hashmap, hashtable

I was given some sample code by my instructor for `HashEntry` class and `HashMap` class. I had to implement the get and put method in the `HashMap` for the standard probing and then linear and quadratic. I have all this working fine, I am able to get and put with any of the probing methods. The next step was to read in a `.csv` file and parse it so the first column is the key and the remaining columns are the rows. This all works great until my key value from the `.csv` goes above the valid `int` value. My question is how can I change the provided code to use a `long` as the key instead of an `int`.

```
public class HashEntry {
  private int key;
  private String value;

  HashEntry(int key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
  }     

  public int getKey() {
        return key;
  }

  public String  getValue() {
        return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String val) {
        this.value = val;
  }
```

}

HashMap

```
public class HashMap {
  private final static int TABLE_SIZE = 1900000;

  HashEntry[] table;

  HashMap() {
      table = new HashEntry[TABLE_SIZE];

      for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)

            table[i] = null;
  }

  public String get(int key) {

      int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);

      while (table[hash] != null && table[hash].getKey() != key)

            hash = (7 * hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;

      if (table[hash] == null)

            return "There is no value at this key";

      else

            return table[hash].getValue();
  }

  public void put(int key, String value) {
      int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);

      while (table[hash] != null && table[hash].getKey() != key)

            hash = (7 * hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;

      table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);
  }

  public void linearprobeput(int key, String value){

          int i = 0;
          int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
          //System.out.println("The hash is " + hash+ "\n");

          while (table[hash] != null && table[hash].getKey() != key)
          {      

                hash = (hash + i) % TABLE_SIZE;
                i++;

                //printing was to verify collisions were being managed correctly
                //System.out.println("Their was a collision now trying with hash'" 
                    //+ hash +" and an i value of "+ i+ "'\n");
          }
          table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);

  }

  public String linearprobeget(int key){

      int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
      int i = 0;

      while (table[hash] != null && table[hash].getKey() != key)
      {
            hash = (hash + i) % TABLE_SIZE;
            i++;
      }

      if (table[hash] == null)

            return "There is no value at this key";

      else

            return table[hash].getValue();

}

  public void quadraticprobeput(int key, String value){

      int i = 0;
      int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
      //System.out.println("The hash is " + hash+ "\n");

      while (table[hash] != null && table[hash].getKey() != key)
      {      

            hash = (hash + (i*i)) % TABLE_SIZE;
            i++;
                        //printing was to verify collisions were being managed correctly
            //System.out.println("Their was a collision now trying with hash'" 
                                //+ hash +" and an i value of "+ i+ "'\n");
      }
      table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);
  }

 public String quadraticprobeget(int key){

      int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
      int i = 0;

      while (table[hash] != null && table[hash].getKey() != key)
      {
            hash = (hash + (i*i)) % TABLE_SIZE;
            i++;
      }

      if (table[hash] == null)

            return "There is no value at this key";

      else

            return table[hash].getValue();

}

}
```

Main

```
HashMap upchm = new HashMap();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
                (new FileReader("UPCtest.csv"));
        //Integer a = null;
        String str=null;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        //lines.split(",")[1]+
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
            //lines.add(str);
            String[] upc= str.split(",");

            Integer val = Integer.valueOf(upc[0]);

            upchm.quadraticprobeput(val, upc[1]+upc[2]);

            System.out.println("UPC = " + val + " Description "+upc[1]+upc[2]);
        }

        //change arraylist to array
        //String[] upc = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
        in.close();
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("The description for the product with upc 123 is " + upchm.quadraticprobeget(123));
        System.out.println("The description for the product with upc 10344 is " + upchm.quadraticprobeget(10344));
```

Sample of some of the lines from the .csv

> 79,,INDIANA LOTTO   93,,treo 700w   123,,Wrsi Riversound cafe cd
>   161,,Dillons/Kroger Employee Coupon ($1.25 credit)
>   2158242769,288/1.12Z,GREEN SUGAR COOKIES4276   2158561631,,HOT COCOA
>   W/BKMK   2158769549,njhjhn,gjfhjbgkj   2160500567,2.25 oz (64)g,Dollar
>   Bar Rich Raspberry   2172307284,,Mixed seasonal flower bouquet
>   2177000074,,4 way 13 AMP Extension Lead (Wilkinson UK)   2184000098,21
>   oz,Christopher's Assorted Fruit Jellies   2187682888,,fairway
>   15400021142,9 Z,WF BOWL CLEANER (JAR   15400021159,8 Z,WF ANTIBAC LIQ
>   SOAP   15400021166,3 RL,WF DECORATOR VALUE   15400021173,64 Z,WF CLEAR
>   AMMONIA   15400021210,128 Z,WF FAB SOFT   15400021319,28 Z,WF DEGREAS
>   ULT DISH   15400021326,28 Z,WF LEMON ULTRA DISH   15400021340,28 Z,WF
>   ANTIBACT DISH LIQ   15400021364,65 Z,WF AUTO DISH DETERGE

Comment: Change datatype of ```key``` to ```long``` instead of ```int```.

Comment: I thought that would be it as well. I went into the HashEntry and changed the key from 'int' to 'long'. I then started making the same changes in my HashMap. But in the HashMap i keep getting 'type mismatch error cannot convert from long to int'

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `long key` instead of `int key` and cast a type when you calculate a bucket in the table:

**HashEntry class**

```
public class HashEntry {
    private long key;
    private String value;
}
```

**HashMap class**

```
public class HashMap {

    private static final int TABLE_SIZE = 1900000;

    private final HashEntry[] table;

    public HashMap() {
        // all elements are null by default
        table = new HashEntry[TABLE_SIZE];
    }

    public String get(long key) {
        int bucket = getBucket(key);

        while (table[bucket] != null && table[bucket].getKey() != key) {
            bucket = (7 * bucket + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
        }

        return getValueByBucket(bucket, key);
    }

    public void put(long key, String value) {
        int bucket = getBucket(key);

        while (table[bucket] != null && table[bucket].getKey() != key) {
            bucket = (7 * bucket + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
        }

        table[bucket] = new HashEntry(key, value);
    }

    public void linearprobeput(long key, String value) {
        int i = 0;
        int bucket = getBucket(key);
        //System.out.println("The hash is " + hash+ "\n");

        while (table[bucket] != null && table[bucket].getKey() != key) {
            bucket = (bucket + i) % TABLE_SIZE;
            i++;

            //printing was to verify collisions were being managed correctly
            //System.out.println("Their was a collision now trying with hash'"
            //+ hash +" and an i value of "+ i+ "'\n");
        }

        table[bucket] = new HashEntry(key, value);
    }

    public String linearprobeget(long key) {
        int i = 0;
        int bucket = getBucket(key);

        while (table[bucket] != null && table[bucket].getKey() != key) {
            bucket = (bucket + i) % TABLE_SIZE;
            i++;
        }

        return getValueByBucket(bucket, key);
    }

    public void quadraticprobeput(long key, String value) {
        int i = 0;
        int bucket = getBucket(key);
        //System.out.println("The hash is " + hash+ "\n");

        while (table[bucket] != null && table[bucket].getKey() != key) {
            bucket = (bucket + (i * i)) % TABLE_SIZE;
            i++;
            //printing was to verify collisions were being managed correctly
            //System.out.println("Their was a collision now trying with hash'"
            //+ hash +" and an i value of "+ i+ "'\n");
        }
        table[bucket] = new HashEntry(key, value);
    }

    public String quadraticprobeget(long key) {
        int i = 0;
        int bucket = getBucket(key);

        while (table[bucket] != null && table[bucket].getKey() != key) {
            bucket = (bucket + (i * i)) % TABLE_SIZE;
            i++;
        }

        return getValueByBucket(bucket, key);
    }

    private static int getBucket(long key) {
        // this is safe, because key % TABLE_SIZE < TABLE_SIZE which is int
        return (int)(key % TABLE_SIZE);
    }

    private String getValueByBucket(int bucket, long key) {
        return table[bucket] == null ? "There is no value at key '" + key + '\'' : table[bucket].getValue();
    }

}
```

I think, and `java.lang.HashMap` uses it as well, that it is better to move `HashEntry` into `HashMap` class:

```
public class HashMap {

    private static final int TABLE_SIZE = 1900000;

    private final Entry[] table;

    public HashMap() {
        // all elements are null by default
        table = new Entry[TABLE_SIZE];
    }

    //...

    private static final class Entry {

        private long key;
        private String value;
    }

}
```

Second, it is better to throw an exception with `There is no value at key` or return `null`. What if you have: `map.put(666, "There is no value at key")` - when you `get` this key, how do you know it this key exists or not?!

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Believe i have a lot better understanding of where I went wrong.